# How to use WP wp_handle_upload() ERROR: File is empty.?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin for WP and it's purpose is Import files(JPG) and collect links or ID.
So I try to open files from the plugin folder and insert it to the media library WP

```
foreach ( $ar as $array ){
    $i = $array['sku'];

    $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'images/' . $array['sku'] . '.jpg' ;

    $exists = file_exists( $path );
    //$existse = file_exists( 'C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\WP\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\sinco_mate\images/930002065858.jpg' );

    if( $exists ){
        foreach (glob( $path) as $filename) {
            //echo "<h3>" . $filename  . "</h3>";

            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );



            $img=fopen($filename, "w+");
            $img_try = wp_handle_upload( $img , $upload_overrides);


            if ( $img_try && ! isset( $img_try['error'] ) ) {
                echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                var_dump( $img_try );
            } else {
                echo $img_try['error'];
            }

            array_push($array_sort,
                array(
                    'pic'=>$i
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

I got this

> File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

But my php.ini is like this and pasture are small

> upload_max_filesize = 100M
>   post_max_size = 100M
>   memory_limit = 128M

How to upload files? Thank you.